# ID's are not increasing in android for table layout

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

In the below code I am displaying ID's numbers starting from 1 dynamically. But every time it displays only 1.

Can any one help me to resolve the issue?

```
for (GetRegisterdPatientListData getRegisterdPatientListData:getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList) {

    RegistrationNo = getRegisterdPatientListData.getRegistrationNo();
    FName = getRegisterdPatientListData.getFName();
    LName = getRegisterdPatientListData.getLName();
    Mobile = getRegisterdPatientListData.getMobile();

    String[] RegistratonList = RegistrationNo.split(",");
    String[] Fnamelist = FName.split (",");
    String[] Lnamelist = LName.split (",");
    String[] Mobilelist = Mobile.split (",");
    numSlots = RegistratonList.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < numSlots; i++) {
        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(getContext());
        tbrow.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());

        tbrow.addView(getTextView(i + numSlots, string.valueOf(i + 1), Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));

        tbrow.addView(getTextView(i + numSlots, RegistratonList[i], Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));

        tbrow.addView(getTextView(i + numSlots, Fnamelist[i].concat(" ").concat(Lnamelist[i]), Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));

        tbrow.addView(getTextView(i + numSlots, Mobilelist[i], Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));

        stk.addView (tbrow);

    }
}
```

Comment: "Displaying 1 only" -> Does this `numSlots` is equal to 1 (so you only get one TextView) **or** that you get the TextViews and all have a value of 1?

Comment: all Yes evrytime value is1

Comment: Let's talk in the chat sometime Jyothi, I'll chastise you...